# What happened with the dead body of Lord Shree Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

In the Mahabharata, I know how Lord Shree Krishna had the end of material life as well as his body, but what happened to his body?

Comment: It is not called by the word 'death',it is mentioned as 'Swargarohana'. And Srimad Bhagavata tells that after getting in yoga posture Krishna became invisible. i.e. There was no physical body in earth after the Sree Krishna Swargarohana.

Comment: @A_runningMind- You are absolutely right. Even Mahabharata says Lord went with his divine chatubhuja form to higher realms viz vaikuntha or heaven.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I discuss in this answer, Krishna was shot by the hunter Jara who mistake his foot for a mouth of a deer.  What happened next is described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16004.htm) of the Mausala Parva of the Mahabharata:

> Coming up, Jara beheld a man dressed in yellow robes, rapt in Yoga and endued with many arms. Regarding himself an offender, and filled with fear, he touched the feet of Keshava. The high-souled one comforted him and then ascended upwards, filling the entire welkin with splendour. When he reached Heaven, Vasava and the twin Ashvinis and Rudra and the Adityas and the Vasus and the Viswedevas, and Munis and Siddhas and many foremost ones among the Gandharvas, with the Apsaras, advanced to receive him. Then, O king, the illustrious Narayana of fierce energy, the Creator and Destroyer of all, that preceptor of Yoga, filling Heaven with his splendour, reached his own inconceivable region. Krishna then met the deities and (celestial) Rishis and Charanas, O king, and the foremost ones among the Gandharvas and many beautiful Apsaras and Siddhas and Saddhyas. All of them, bending in humility, worshipped him. The deities all saluted him, O monarch, and many foremost of Munis and Rishis worshipped him who was the Lord of all. The Gandharvas waited on him, hymning his praises, and Indra also joyfully praised him.

But this is just a description of how Krishna's soul ascending to Devaloka (Vishnu's atmaswarupa, which is why it's described as many-armed), because a [later chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16007.htm) of the Mausala Parva describes how Arjuna cremated Krishna's physical body:

> Searching out the bodies then of Rama and Vasudeva, Arjuna caused them to be burnt by persons skilled in that act. The son of Pandu, having next performed duly those sraddha rites that are done to the dead, quickly set out on the seventh day, mounting on his car.

I should add that at least according to the [local legends](http://books.google.com/books?id=0z02cZe8PU8C&lpg=PA152&ots=NjGr4IqHtw&dq=arjuna%20%22krishna's%20body%22&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Orissa, when Arjuna was cremating Krishna's body the heart was incapable of being consumed by the fire, so Arjuna threw it in the sea, and the heart now resides within the Krishna idol of the famous Puri Jagannath Temple.

Comment: Comments have been moved to chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26232/discussion-on-answer-by-keshav-srinivasan-what-happened-with-the-dead-body-of-lo

Comment: How can you say the heart of Krishna is there?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, that's the story of the Puri Jagannath temple.

Comment: Mb nowhere mentions that it was his soul/atma swarupa that ascended. When he shot the arrow, its mentioned that he got repentant in seeing the multi armed king. It means that it hit him in when he was in his four/multi armed formed form.
And moreover, this somewhat contradicts sb version which specifically mentions that he went to his abode with his own body without burning. And, generally, sb is more authoritative than mb  as it widely commented by saints and acharyas of various sects and have more than 80 sankrit commentaries.also sb mentioned that this episode is maya rachitam. (11.30.49)