# What was the previous life of lord Krishna?

Tags: krishna, avatars, rebirth

I've heard little accounts of Shri Krishna's past life, such as - he was Shri Rama in his past life. I recently heard he could have been Lakshmana (Rama's brother), in the previous incarnation too.
What was his past life?

Comment: the answer is not sufficient

Comment: Refer [my answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16314/1049), where a section describes Shri Krishna's previous births. He was Not Shri RAma, as RAma attained SamAdhi at end of his life.